# Is there a better way to log information in Scala than using a function?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm writing a web service and am often sending messages over HTTPS.

```
val response = sendJson(JsonUtil.getTextMessageJson("Sorry I don't understand what day you want. You can say " + "things like \"tomorrow\" or \"next Friday\""))
```

I could follow this call with onComplete {} and handle the resulting Success or Failure but since I do this so often I have written a simple function in a helper class:

```
def logSendResult(response: Future[WSResponse])(implicit userId: String): Unit = {
response onComplete {
  case Success(res) => Logger.info("Message to " + userId + " sent successfully with " +
    "response code: " + res.status)
  case Failure(exception) => Logger.info("Message to " + userId + " failed with " +
    "exception: " + exception.getMessage)
}
```

}

Which I then call with:

```
LogUtils.logSendResult(response)
```

This is working fine but I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I don't use Play, but from a quick google search it looks like HttpFilters is what you may need:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a cross cutting concerns. If not handled properly might cause problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern

AOP (aspect oriented programming) can fix 'cross cutting concerns'.

Here is a sample AOP program using AspectJ library in scala.
This sample aspect will print Method, its input and result detail, when a method is entered annotated with the @Loggable annotation and finished execution.

https://github.com/knoldus/CrossCuttingConcern_Scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/knoldus/aspect/Aspect.scala

Hope this help. Best of luck!

Comment: I previously used AOP for logging when I was doing Java / Spring development. I was hoping there was something more innate to the Scala language itself to help me solve the problem but as you suggest the concern is indeed cross cutting.

Answer (score 0):

## HTTP Filters

This sounds like a good application of a Filter https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters

In the example they even show ho to Build a logging Filter.